# Facebook Graph API v1.0 does not return results for hashtag search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

I currently try to fetch public posts containing a certain hashtag using Graph API v1.0.

I've learned that :

- Hashtag search was deprecated in FB Graph API v2.0
- Querying hashtag with FB Graph API v1.0 only works for Apps created before April, 30th 2014
- A valid access token has to be used
- The researched term has to be preceded with "%23" in place of "#"

I made some tests with the Graph API Explorer using the v1.0 with the following GET url :

**https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=%23pepsi** (This works! I receive a post hashtagged with Pepsi).

Now, I made some public posts using #sltest on Facebook (I posted 3 days ago and tested everyday, but none of those posts appears in results).
When I try to fetch them with the same parameters :

**https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=%23sltest** (I receive nothing :-(, no errors, only an empty "data" Array).

Does anyone has an explanation of what's going on?

Comment: I think that search API is randomize and no 100% guarantee what you expected to see even though you can search https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/sltest doesn't means you can get the results from API calls. You can get pepsi response because this hashtag is famous, does it make sense to you? Moreover this feature is deprecated 11 months to go, so  i believe no further improvement effort from Facebook enginering team will pay on it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It makes sense. I tried with another less famous hashtag we created only 1 week ago. This hashtag has only 3 posts and results are fetched by FB Graph API v1.0.
I will continue to investigate and post a response when I get something tangible... Any help is more than welcome ;-)

Comment: After some researches : It seems like Facebook Api index only posts with a certain amount of views during a certain period of time.

Comment: A post could be indexed in the FB Api when it reaches a number of views and then disappear when this amount of views decrease on a time period.
In other words, only posts with a current high reach are indexed in the Api. The 3 posts I was talking about yesterday with a newly and not famous hashtag were posted on a Facebook Group with a high pageviews, that's the reason why they were indexed. Thanks for your help 林果皞 !